# Java XML DOM int value

Tags: java, xml, dom

Say I have a line within an xml file that is:

`<number> 7 </number>`

I want to store the value of 7 in an integer in java, but dont know how.. .heres my code so far

```
if (nodelist.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&
                                ((Element) nodelist).getTagName().equals("number")){
                            //store value as int (int value = number in tags)
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int seven = Integer.parseInt(theNode.getNodeValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a utility like [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/) that wraps the standard DOM API to simplify things. Here's how you could access that `<number/>` element:

```
Integer seven = $(document).find("number").text(Integer.class);
```

instead of

```
Integer seven = Integer.parseInt(
  ((Element) document.getElementsByName("name").item(0)).getTextContent());
```